# Re-enabling extension installs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I found the new change that you can't install Chrome extensions/userscripts without saving them and dragging them into Chrome quite annoying. As such I have set forth to revert this to the old way it was.

I read the documentation here: http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources that says to add a registry key and so I have done, as shown below. However when attempting to install an extension I still get an error that they can only be installed from the Chrome webstore. Did I add the registry entries wrong or something?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\ExtensionInstallSources]
"1"="http://*"
"2"="https://*"
```

Answer (score 5):

## This answer is [obsolete as of Chrome 36](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=357750)

---

Instead of editing the registry, you can also make Chrome to behave in the old way via the [**`--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`**](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#enable-easy-off-store-extension-install) flag.

Under Windows, create a shortcut to your Chrome executable. Then edit the shortcut, and append `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` to "Target". See the screenshot below:

[image]

Some observations:

- I've added the `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` flag after `chrome.exe`.
- After starting Chrome, I visited a website that links to a `.crx` file that is not hosted in the Chrome web store.
- Because of the flag, Chrome 20 doesn't show the *"Extensions, apps, and user scripts can only be added from the Chrome Web Store"* message any more. Instead (see bottom), Chrome asks me whether it's OK to install the extension - exactly as before.

This command line switch also works for Chromium/Chrome, under Linux and OSX.

Comment: Thanks, this works however I'd still like to know how the registry entry option works.

Comment: @Arimil Have you already looked at one of the bug reports, by the way? [Google `site:code.google.com/p/chromium/issues ExtensionInstallSources`](https://www.google.nl/search?q=site%3Acode.google.com%2Fp%2Fchromium%2Fissues+ExtensionInstallSources)

Comment: Hm, that bug report says that there isn't a problem. However someone also posted about using an <all_urls> value which seems to work. Unlike me wildcarding the whole url. So this works now, thanks.

Comment: @Arimil Can you unaccept my answer? The proposed method does not work any more in recent Chrome versions.

Comment: How to do it in the MAC OS, where i would add "--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install" this line when on mac ?

Comment: @nadeemgc Please read the top of the answer, this method does not work any more, unfortunately. Anyway, see http://superuser.com/questions/157484/start-google-chrome-on-mac-with-command-line-switches if you want to pass the command-line argument anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you ever find yourself in the situation where the `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` flag doesn't work (e.g. future version?) or you don't want to use it, then there is an alternative method.

You can install extensions with a plain vanilla install of Chrome by dragging .CRX extension files onto the Extensions panel in Settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This appears to be the only way to install a private extension as of May 2016.