# Is there anyway to install an extention without visiting to google app store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Is there anyway to install an extention without visiting to google app store? 
For example I want visitors, can install my extention just one clicking a facebook ad or a banner?

Is it possible?

I read some article that mentioning about to verified site ownership to do this. But I want to make advertisement on facebook so I wouldn't be owner of the web page...

Does anyone have information on this subject?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on the Chrome shortcut
- In the Target field, add `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` after what's already there, let a space before
- Save and start Chrome

Comment: You can't expect from an ordinary user that they have enabled this flag. For the ones who are more visually oriented, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049366/re-enabling-extension-installs/12071194#12071194) for a guiding screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [*inline installation*](https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation), performed via `chrome.webstore.install`.

In your webpage:

- include `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item" href="https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/itemID">`, where the URL is the address of your extension
- then. call `chrome.webstore.install()`.

Unfortunately, you can't do either of those things on a basic Facebook page, but you could do it on a web page you can fully control.

Comment: is there anyway that visitors can install an extension clicking a banner or facebook ad without verifing a web page ? OMG..

Comment: @Burcak No, there is not. Inline installation is as close as you can get, and that requires site verification (see the last section of the page I linked in my answer). If you want to perform the install from a site you don't own, you'll have to send your visitors to the Web Store page.