How to programmatically download CRX file of my own chrome extension which is not published
Since in the latest version of chrome, we cannot install the self-signed CRX files. The only possible path to publish chrome extensions internally in our workplace seems to be creating a new item on the chrome extension developer portal, uploading files programmatically using https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/api, and downloading programmatically.
However, I am unable to download files programmatically or find attributes to link to the crx file.
I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/crx3 package to self sign the zip file but it is not working in my chrome with version `124.0.6367.78 (Official Build) (arm64) `

Before trying to hack your way through Google, it may be worth looking at a couple other options - while some of them can be obsolote, some others may still work https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/chrome-enterprise/publishing-extensions-for-the-enterprise https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9296680 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452817/is-it-possible-to-create-a-chrome-extension-for-private-distribution-outside-chr https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2714278
