# Packaged App - install from outside of app store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a packaged app, but I want to distribute it through my own website - outside of the Google Chrome Web Store. So when user lands on my website, they receive the dialogue box to 'install' my app, and can install it, independently of the Chrome Web Store.

Is it at all possible?

Thanks in advance -

Comment: Yes, see https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/inline_installation

Comment: Hmm. This is interesting. Unfortunately it seems the app still needs to *reside* in the Google Web Store. This is just a convenience method that allows the user to avoid actually visiting the web store, but the app code still needs to be hosted in the web store.

So, it seems there is no way to pull an app into Chrome, unless the app itself is signed and hosted by Google?

Comment: The source must be hosted in the CWS. It's possible to host the code outside the Store, but the user must enable a flag to get the feature (`--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`).

Comment: That answers my question! Thanks. Would you like to convert this into an answer, so I can provide you some reputation?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/120743/how-to-install-extensions-from-outside-the-chrome-web-store/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-enabling extension installs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049366/re-enabling-extension-installs)

Comment: Instead of posting a new answer, I'll just mark the question as a duplicate of a question I've answered before.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do it without `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` -- it's just a little bit trickier for users. You will have to tell your users to do the following:

1. Download the .crx file from your website.
2. Navigate to chrome://extensions.
3. Drag the .crx file from the file explorer onto the extensions page.

This will install the packaged app into Chrome completely independently of the Web Store.