# not able to install chrome extension by DnD after v30

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In the back good old days, we can install chrome extension offline by drag and drop the crx file into chrome://extensions panel, but that will fail with the latest chrome now, saying "this can only be added from the chrome web store", I'm running 30.0.1599.101, Windows-7 64-bit

Is there any alternative way to offline install chrome extension ?

**Update**: this is not duplicate question of [Re-enabling extension installs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12049366/re-enabling-extension-installs)

please notice the difference of address bar in below snaps

1. DnD is not working anyway. We can DnD the crx file into Chrome, and Chrome knows it is one extension. [image: Install Chrome Extension by DnD is not working. Chorme 30.0.1599.101 (Official Build 227552) m, Windows OS]
2. --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install is not working either. I was asked to confirm install the extension, and I said Yes, please do it, but failed with the indicator progress bar disappears[image]

Comment: It works fine for me (same version of Chrome on Windows).

Comment: Also it might be a problem with the `crx` file itself. Open the console using `Tools->Developer tools` and check the console when installing the extension.

Comment: Are you on Windows? http://blog.chromium.org/2013/11/protecting-windows-users-from-malicious.html

Comment: @RobW Yes this is Window-7 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `crx` file install is not working, the alternate way is to unzip the crx file using an archive manager like 7-zip.

Then to install the extension :

- Go to the Extensions page, `chrome://settings/extension`
- Activate `Developer mode`
- Select `Load unpacked extension...`
- Select your unpacked extension folder.

Comment: Yeah but he didn't precise the platform or if he's using chromium. On linux with Chromium 30.0x the Drag`n`Drop is disabled and an error popup appears.

Comment: Interesting. Is it disabled in "developer mode" as well ?

Comment: Yeah in both mode I get a popup saying "This can only be added from the Chrome Web Store."